# UIPicker view items are not scrolled while try to scroll the picker items in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In my UIPicker contain number of item and default selected row is set as first item in the picker. What my problem when I try to scroll items in picker scrolling is only worked while hold the first item and move the items but If holding second or any other items in the picker and try to scrolling it doesn't worked. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

```
   public static UIPickerView SelectFontSize()
    {
        ListOfFontSizes = new List<string>();

        ListOfFontSizes.Add("Select");
        int i = 10;

        while (i < 60)
        {
            ListOfFontSizes.Add(i.ToString());

            i += 2;
        }

        _manageFontsizePicker = new UIPickerView
        {
            Hidden = true,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White
        };

        _manageFontsizePicker.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;

        return _manageFontsizePicker;
    }


    private void SelectFontSize()
    {
        _manageFontSizePicker = PickerHelper.SelectFontSize();

        _manageFontSizePickerModel = new ManageFontSizePickerModel(PickerHelper.ListOfFontSizes);

        _manageFontSizePicker.Model = _manageFontSizePickerModel;

        _manageFontSizePicker.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, _width - 20, 185);

        _manageFontSizePicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;

        _managgeFontSizePicker.SelectedRowInComponent(0);
      }
```

[image]

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: I have update my code in question.

Comment: try below code may provide i try my best